# Setting VBA to read personal inbox

Tags: outlook

trying to get some VBA code together to basically be able to run my rules from a button on my toolbar within outlook 2007. The following code runs the rules on my exchange server inbox, which is empty as everything moves to my "Personal Inbox". I just want to change the code below to read my personal inbox and not my exchange mailbox inbox. Have searched on the web and cant find my answer and hence my post -

```
Sub RunAllInboxRules()
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim ruleList As String
'On Error Resume Next


' get default store (where rules live)
Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
' get rules
Set myRules = st.GetRules

' iterate all the rules
For Each rl In myRules
    ' determine if it's an Inbox rule
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then
        ' if so, run it
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        count = count + 1
        ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
    End If
Next

' tell the user what you did
ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllInboxRules"

Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have tested on my machine. This logs into the mailbox you are logged onto and runs the rules accordingly

```
Sub RunAllInboxRules()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim ruleList As String
Dim fldInbox As Object
Dim gnspNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

'On Error Resume Next

' get default store (where rules live)

'Logs into Outlook session
    Set objOL = Outlook.Application
    Set gnspNameSpace = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI") 'Outlook Object
   'Logs into the default Mailbox Inbox

'set the store to the mailbox

Set st = gnspNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Store

' get rules

Set myRules = st.GetRules

' iterate all the rules
For Each rl In myRules
    ' determine if it's an Inbox rule
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then
        ' if so, run it
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        count = count + 1
        ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
    End If
Next

' tell the user what you did
ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllInboxRules"

Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub
```