# Sequential process Outlook rules

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I use a outlook rule to process incoming mail via a VBA macro.
in the vba various actions are triggerd to process attachments of the incoming mail.

The problem is, there somethimes is a stack of e-mails that need to be processed.
I cant seem to find a way how to trigger the one by one.
I want to wait a few seconds before processing the next mail, if there is a stack.
Putting a sleep method in the macro doesnt seem to have effect. the rule doesnt seem to wait for the previous message to be done.

My method i  something like:

Is there a way to accomplish this behaviour?

```
Private Sub ProcessMail(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

        DoProcessingMethod 

    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Putting a wait or sleep in the method doesnt cause it to be processed one by one.

Comment: Seeing your code might help :)

Comment: @brettdj Added the method outline

Comment: I think you're better off using ItemAdd to run your code on the emails. That way the code will run sequentially. Depending on the rule will take control away from the code.

Comment: Sue Mosher has a useful link [here](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62) on options to process incoming email. `NewMailEx event` and `ItemAdd` are briefly described

Comment: You could implement your own waiting queue. This could be a collection sorted by arrival times. Once a mail comes in, your rule handler checks if there are waiting items. If there are, the new mail is put to the end of the queue. A timer event handler is used to process the waiting items. For security reasons, I would store the mails in some temporary folder to prevent data loss.

Answer (score 1):

GD Arnold,

You could indeed use the `ItemAdd` option as per @Brett's answer.

I use a similar process to automatically upload received data (as attachment in an email) and upload this to a MySQL database. The action is triggered by the ItemAdd method and mails are checked one-by-one.

Simplified instructions:

Add a Class to your VBA code named "EventClassModule"

In your class, type

```
Public WithEvents dItems As Outlook.Items
```

In your ThisOutlookSession make a sub that registers the event_handler:

```
Sub Register_Event_Handler()

    Set myClass.dItems = Outlook.Items

End Sub
```

In your ThisOutlookSession make a sub that handles the ItemAdd event as below:

```
Private Sub dItems_ItemAdd(ByVal newItem As Object)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
  If newItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set msg = newItem
    'Do something with the msg item, check rules, check subject, check whatever
    'This will process messages when the arrive in your mailbox one by one.


  End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

These steps should provide you with a sub that is triggered when a new mail arrives.

You could then call a function/sub like below.
The below sub runs all rules based on an optional `ruleSet` variable, it checks the `rule.Name` against the ruleSet and if the `ruleSet` string exists in the `rule.Name` then it executes some code. This way you can have multiple rules and only execute some of them based on which 'ruleSet' they are part of. You can define that by altering their name.

It's a refinement of the 'Run Rules' option in Outlook.

Some of this code came frome here: [Setting VBA to read personal inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807739/setting-vba-to-read-personal-inbox)

```
Sub runRules(Optional ruleSet As String)
    Dim olStore As Outlook.Store
    Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim tmpInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim tmpSent As Outlook.Folder

    Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
    'On Error Resume Next
    'toTmpBox (ruleSet)

    ' get default store (where rules live)
    Set olStore = Application.Session.DefaultStore

    With olStore
        Set tmpInbox = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) '.Folders("tmpInbox")
        Set tmpSent = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail) '.Folders("tmpSentBox")
    End With

    ' get rules
    Set myRules = olStore.GetRules

    ' iterate through all the rules
    For Each rl In myRules
            Debug.Print rl.Conditions.Body.Enabled & " " & rl.Conditions.Body.Text

            If InStr(LCase(rl.Name), ruleSet) > 0 And (rl.Enabled) Then

                rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=tmpInbox

                If ruleSet = "autorun" Then
                    rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=olStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

                End If

                ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
            End If
    Next


    ' tell the user what you did
    ruleList = "These rules were executed " & _
          vbCrLf & ruleList
    MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunMyRules"

CleanUp:

    Set olStore = Nothing
    Set tmpInbox = Nothing
    Set tmpSent = Nothing

    Set rl = Nothing
    Set myRules = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar problem.  In my case my tool would run at regular time interval and each time I had to capture new emails only.  Now new emails could be one or multiple.  the solution I found was as given below.

Each time the tool would run.   it will capture the new emails and just mark a simple ',' or '|' anything of your choice at the end of the subject in such a way that no one will notice.  Now next time when the tool runs it checks if the emails received for the entire day or two (based on your requirements) has those markers or not.

This solution works if the email communication is one way.  If we use these email for chain emails then their is another solution.

Here you will have to save the time max time of emails captured in the last run.  Now each time you run you just have to run it for the entire day and put an if statement that is should be greater then time last captured.

Now to store the max time you might need to create a folder and an email.  The email can help you to store the each time the run happens

`item.subject = maxtime
item.save`